# Laravel: whereHas->WhereHas->Where query. Need to add wherePivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am selecting all the `ScheduledPrograms` from a certain data range that has `Attendees` that belong to a certain `User`. I want to add a filter to select only the `SchduledPrograms` where the pivot field `registered=1`

I.E. I need to add a `wherePivot('registered', 1)` for the many-to-many relation `scheduledPrograms->attendees`. I How do I do this? My mind is scrambled from all the where clauses.

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
              ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
              ->whereHas('attendees', function($q) use($user)
              {
                  $q->whereHas('user', function($q) use($user){
                      $q->where('id', $user->id);
                  });
               })->get();
```

**Models**

```
Attendee->belongsTo('User')   
        ->belongsToMany('ScheduledPrograms')

User->hasMany('Attendee')

ScheduledProgram->belongsToMany('Attendee')
```

`
**ScheduledProgram Model**

```
  public function attendees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Attendee', 'prog_bookings')->withPivot('registered','paid');
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

`wherePivot()` can be used only for `belongsToMany` instances, but `whereHas()` closure function receives `Builder` instance instead.

So you can't use `wherePivot()` inside `whereHas()`.

Answer (score 5):

Method `wherePivot` works with model instances, not with the Model Query Builder.

I think when using `whereHas` method, the pivot table is already joined by eloquent, so **just start using it** in the `whereHas` method:

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
          ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
          ->whereHas('attendees', function($q) use($user)
          {
              $q
                  //========= See this: =========
                  ->where('prog_bookings.registered', '1')
                  ->whereHas('user', function($q) use($user){
                      $q->where('id', $user->id);
                  });
           })
           ->wherePivot('registered', 1)
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try anything? What error do you get?

If the 'registered' field is in the pivot table between ScheduledPrograms and Atendees relation, you can add the where clause before the get():

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
          ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
          ->whereHas('attendees', function($q) use($user)
          {
              $q->whereHas('user', function($q) use($user){
                  $q->where('id', $user->id);
              });
           })
           ->wherePivot('registered', 1)
           ->get();
```

Comment: My `registered` field is where you say, but I named the pivot table 'bookings' instead of letting it use the default name. I tried as you said but I get the error `Unknown column 'pivot'`.

Comment: mm if you didn't use conventions you must set the pivot table name in the relationship definition, like this:                                                               $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'foo_id'); So, using your names, ScheduledProgram model should be: $this->belongsToMany('Atendee', 'bookings', 'scheduled_program_id', 'atendee_id')->withPivot('registered');

Comment: My model appears to be set correctly. I edited my post to include the pivot relation in my model. It seems like wherePivot is behaving like the with_Variable_ method and making a _where_ clause using whatever follows _where_ as the column name. Here is the error showing the SQL statement being run.  http://imgur.com/Y2XUOsE

Comment: Yeah. I'm sorry. My answer is wrong. I'll edit it. I see the two nested whereHas are a bit confusing. What happens if you write $attendeesIds = $user->attendees()->get()->lists('id'), and then ScheduledProgram::whereHas('attendees', function($q) use ($attendeesIds){ $q->whereIn('attendees.id', $attendeesIds); })->where.....->get(); It looks like a mess written here. I hope I didn't make mistakes. Give it a try

Comment: same error: `unknown column 'pivot'` but the SQL looks cleaner. http://imgur.com/klA0aXP. I think the wherePivot does not work unless it is used in a chain like '$attendee->scheduledPrograms()->wherePivot(...`

Comment: I solved the error by moving the wherePivot into the model `public function registeredAttendees() { return $this->attendees()->wherePivot('registered',1); }` and then `whereHas('attendees'...` becomes `whereHas('registeredAttendees'...`